# Blazor service is null doing property injection

Tags: blazor-client-side

I have a class that I am doing property injection.

Calling methods of this service object does nothing, no errors, exceptions, etc.

When I check to see if the service is null, it is. This seems like this should be a null exception.

I am checking the service null in a SignalR "ON" call back so it looks like there maybe a race condition, but

My solution was to change it to a constructor inject, but I am wondering why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.

From what I can tell, [Inject] works with razor pages. If you want to inject into a class, you need to use the constructor method.

See section about IJSRuntime:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: It doesn't always fail, but I think it is kind of odd that I can try calling methods and not get an error.